# JPA: Aggregation on day of week

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I see JPA is short on providing date/time extraction functions. For example how to achieve following simple goal

```
calculate total revenue by given days of week (i.e. revenue only on Friday, Saturday, Sunday)?
```

Ideally there should be an API so

```
select sum(revenue) from salesreport where day_of_week(date) in (:daysList);
```

I see no easy way to make it happen in JPA (and I am using OpenJPA) rather than a native query. Some JPA vendor provides `Year()`, `Month()`, `Day()` (day of month) but none for day of week

Comment: Does OpenJPA provide a vendor extension to use SQL functions in JPQL (it is standard in JPA 2.1 but OpenJPA doesn't support that) ? If so then you could make use of an SQL function to get the day of week part

Comment: @Neil Stockton thanks but isn't that becomes equivalence of using native query (DB vendor specific)?

Answer (score 1):

With Hibernate, you can

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM d.tstamp), SUM(d.revenue) 
FROM Dosh d 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM d.tstamp)
```

For this to work, the underlying RDBMS must support the EXTRACT function.

I have seen a report claiming the same works on EclipseLink.